# ASP.Net dropdownlist lost selectedvalue if data added with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario where I have added options in dropdownlist by Jquery.

When I do submit the form then at code behind I am not getting the selected value of the dropdownlist which I bounded through JQuery.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET (and all other server-side languages), if you make changes to elements to the HTML on the client using client-side scripting (such as javascript/jQuery), those changes will only be sent back to the server if they are in form elements (such as `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`).

If you add things via jQuery, then you must record that fact in one of the controls that will be posted back to the server, and then on the server you must react to that fact and rebuild the dropdown.